# Android - How to update Parent AlertDialog from a Child AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am building a calendar app where clicking on a calendar date will pop up an `AlertDialog` which shows the list of events added on that particular date.

[image]

I am populating this dialog using a custom `ArrayAdapter`. I have added a delete button against each of the items.

The goal is, when the user clicks on the delete button, a secondary pop up appears, and asks user to conform the delete action.

Now the problem is, when user confirms the delete action, I want the confirmation dialog (Child dialog) to close, and the corresponding item removed from the Parent Dialog.

[image]

How can I achieve this? This is my custom adapter class so far.

```
class EventDialogAdapter(
context: Context,
events: Array<EventItem>
) : ArrayAdapter<EventItem>(context, 0, events) {

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_dialog_event, parent, false)

    val eventItem = getItem(position)

    if (eventItem != null) {
        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.colorView).setBackgroundColor(eventItem.color)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.eventNameView).text = eventItem.eventName

        // set close buton
        val closeButton : ImageButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnDeleteEvent)

        closeButton.setOnClickListener {
            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)

            // set message of alert dialog
            dialogBuilder.setMessage(eventItem.eventName + ":\n\nAre you sure to delete this event?")
                // if the dialog is cancelable
                .setCancelable(false)
                // positive button text and action
                .setPositiveButton("Delete", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    //======================================================================                        
                    // DO something here to update the Parent dialog ????????
                    //======================================================================
                })
                // negative button text and action
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                        dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                })

            // create dialog box
            val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
            // set title for alert dialog box
            alert.setTitle("Confirm")
            // show alert dialog
            alert.show()
        }

    }

    return view
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the below method.

First I created an AlertDialog variable in my Adapter class.

```
lateinit var _parentDialog : androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

fun SetParentDialog(parentDialog : androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog )
{
    _parentDialog = parentDialog
}
```

Then while building the parent dialog, I passed the reference of the parent dialog like this.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())            

        val adapter = EventDialogAdapter(requireContext(), eventItems)
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, null)

        val dialog = builder.create()
        adapter.SetParentDialog(dialog)
        dialog.show()
```

Then on Delete button click in the Adapater class:

```
.setPositiveButton("Delete", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    // delete event from DB                        
                    dialog.cancel()

                    var myVariable = _parentDialog
                    // Do stuff here
                })
```